# Jquery nth-child that is not 3n+6

Tags: jquery, html, dom, css, jquery-selectors

Hi im trying to access every child that is not 3n+6
i.e something like this `$('div:nth-child(!3n+6)')`
is there a way to select every child that is not 3n+6 in jquery

Comment: Just a side not that you should really avoid a class called `div` since it's also the name of an HTML element and can easily get confusing.

Comment: sorry i didn't mean it as a class. have edited the question

Comment: No problem :) It doesn't change your question. Just thought I'd throw it out there as warning.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
$('div:not(:nth-child(3n+6))')
```

should work fine

Comment: +1 for mind-reading... I was just about to say that... lol, it's fun watching your upvotes increase...

Answer (score 3):

You can use [:not()](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) to specify some element to avoid.

```
$('.div:not(:nth-child(3n+6))')
```

or

```
$('.div').not(":nth-child(3n+6)")
```